# Profile is showing tabs in portugese?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I went into my profile just recently and i saw this

[image]

as you can see, just the tabs for my profile are in portugese. i asked this in the chat room i'm always in to see if anyone else was getting the same thing and apparently not. i was told to check my language settings. since i have never touched the PC ones i checked my browser

[image: Settings]

and just to show it isn't just a Beta Site, Stack Overflow

[image: Stack Overflow]

However it's not happening here on Meta

[image: Meta.SE]

I am wondering what's going on here and how can i fix it?

Comment: The funny thing is that the duplication link points to a question with *no* answer

Comment: @chouaib there was an answer before but it had a score of -3 so i dare say someone deleted it